# ipa app not installing inspite of having a valid provisioning

Tags: ios, ipad, installation, ipa

I am trying to install an ipa file in my iPad. It is an enterprise app and I have given my UDID for them to create a provisioning file.

Now i have the ipa and the provisioning file. I have successfully installed the provisioning file in my iPad, but my app is not getting installed. Tried testflight too. No luck.

Below is the console logs:

```
>     Jun 18 16:18:39 Adobe-SiteCatalyst-iPad lockdownd[46] <Notice>: 015da000      __copy_itunes_value_block_invoke_0:
> com.apple.mobile.iTunes.store/PurchaseTypes -> (null)
>     Jun 18 16:18:42 Adobe-SiteCatalyst-iPad installd[55] <Error>: 0x255000 handle_install:         Install of
> "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/IMF_Finances20140617_P_OmnitureAdobe
> (1).ipa"    requested by itunesstored
>     Jun 18 16:18:42 Adobe-SiteCatalyst-iPad installd[55] <Error>: 0x255000 peruse_package: App    info dict loaded from
> "/var/tmp/install_staging.wn8amG/foo_extracted/Payload/IMF
> Finances.app"   did not have bundle identifier
>     Jun 18 16:18:42 Adobe-SiteCatalyst-iPad installd[55] <Error>: 0x255000 stage_package:   Could not peruse package at
> /var/tmp/install_staging.wn8amG/foo_extracted
>     Jun 18 16:18:42 Adobe-SiteCatalyst-iPad itunesstored[72] <Error>: 0x1a5a000   MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
>     Jun 18 16:18:42 Adobe-SiteCatalyst-iPad installd[55] <Error>: 0x255000     MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Could not stage the
> package
>     Jun 18 16:18:42 Adobe-SiteCatalyst-iPad installd[55] <Error>: 0x255000 handle_install: API failed
>     Jun 18 16:18:42 Adobe-SiteCatalyst-iPad mobile_assertion_agent[107] <Notice>: service_one_connection:
> Connection closed for client iTunes.
>     Jun 18 16:19:01 Adobe-SiteCatalyst-iPad profiled[3865] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Idled.
>     Jun 18 16:19:01 Adobe-SiteCatalyst-iPad profiled[3865] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service stopping.
```

I have tried to unzip the ipa file and look into embedded.mobileprovision and verified my UDID is there in the ProvisionedDevices

Thanks in advance for your help...